# Any good source of information on EU based postdoctoral/researcher funding opportunities

Tags: research-process, funding, postdocs, eu

I have read several posts on the forum but there seems no good information hub for EU based postdoctoral/researcher funding opportunities. I will be grateful if someone can give me a start.

By the way, I have found this [list](https://www.mariecuriealumni.eu/newsletter/10-websites-you-need-know-european-funding-opportunities) myself.

Comment: Don't know of any *umbrella* information hub as such (I suspect if search engines haven't helped, then it's rather unlikely you would find many of such sites anyway). For STEM fields, you can check out this [page](http://brightrecruits.com/jobs/academic-postdoc/). It tends to be more UK-centric though. Or here's another page for [science jobs](http://jobs.sciencecareers.org/jobs/europe/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest two options 1) applying for your own funding and/or 2) apply for a job where someone has aquired funding and is looking for a postdoc. Option #1 is far more desirable - though also more risky.

For option 1) There are several EU funding options (many country specific). Not knowing your field, you might have a look the EU call; http://europa.eu/about-eu/funding-grants/

For option 2) Academics post positions for postdocs all the time. Akadeus.com is a good starting point. https://www.akadeus.com/

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [EURAXESS portal](http://ec.europa.eu/euraxess/) by the European Commission. Besides their job listing, they offer information and services to support relocation to another country, and information for non-european researchers wishing to work in Europe. If you're looking at a specific country, you can also check out the [national portals](http://ec.europa.eu/euraxess/index.cfm/jobs/nationalPortals).